# Hide from view in Bryntum Scheduler

Tags: vue.js, bryntum-scheduler

In the Bryntum scheduler UI, can we hide a resource and the entire day activity row temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, just look at the store filter API: https://bryntum.com/docs/scheduler/#Core/data/Store#function-filterBy

```
scheduler.resourceStore.filterBy(resource => resource.age > 25);
```

Then to reset filters:

https://bryntum.com/docs/scheduler/#Core/data/Store#function-clearFilters

Comment: Actually I have a option called "hide from view" next to the resource name in bryntum scheduler. I want to Hide that particular resource  from the screen upon user request. Will this answer workout for the mentioned action?

Comment: Also, How to pass the resourceID to the filterby method to hide that resource from View

Comment: Yes, if you filter out a resource it will not longer be shown.